# Merge 5 tags? shares, stocks, stock-analysis, stock-exchanges, stock-markets

Tags: discussion

Which of these 5 tags can be merged? Which differ, and how?

## [shares](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/shares) [stocks](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/stocks) [stock-analysis](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/stock-analysis) [stock-exchanges](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/stock-exchanges) [stock-markets](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/stock-markets)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Stock-exchanges and stock-markets, maybe. If there's a difference, I don't know what it is.

Shares and stocks, I'm not sure of. You can have shares in something that aren't formally shares of stock -- I have a share in a local community funded farm, for example -- but I don't know whether that distinction will ever apply here.

Analysis is probably separate. Whether that should be merged/broadened to investment-analysis, I dunno.

Comment: a stock exchange can encompass multiple markets and venues - see ICE for example - so they are distinct. Stocks and shares differ as you stated

Comment: I'm not sure the typical question author is going to understand or correctly apply the exchange versus market distinction, but I don't have enough opinion to have a preference.

Comment: I feel that a proper tag description rather than anything else is the prudent course of action

Comment: Good enough, if someone is volunteering to do that. I'm not it, clearly.